# How do I add additional NuGet package sources to Visual Studio Code on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, nuget, signalr, visual-studio-code

I'd like to add the [ASP.NET Core release branch feed](https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcore-ci-release) to my VS Code feeds, so I can try out an RTM version of SignalR Core which might be compatible with my .NET Core 1.1.0 build.

I found a number of posts recommending [.NET Core Project Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ksubedi.net-core-project-manager) for this purpose, but I can't find the appropriate NuGet.config file on my MBP, nor any obvious UX to add additional package sources.

Where do I add new package sources for NuGet on VS Code for Mac OS X?

Comment: What is an MBP?

Comment: Macbook Pro I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a nuget.config file in your project's directory that contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="ASP.NET Core CI Release" 
         value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-ci-release/api/v3/index." />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Make sure that you run vscode from that directory or from a descendant of that directory.

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior

Comment: Thanks! Quite an obvious one now I think about it—currently undocumented anywhere I could find, but makes perfect sense.